# Search for loops of linked numbers

Tags: python

I need to find the loops from a file, which is organized as:

```
28 36

17 43

36 28

43 69

69 17

8 94
```

In the example, I would like to identify `[28, 36]` as one list, since I have `28 -> 36`, then `36 -> 28`. And `[17, 43, 69]` as another list, for the same reason. If the loop is not closed, such as 8 and 94 above, I don't want them.

What is the pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What are you looking to get as the end result?  Do you want to list each of the cycles found or a set of all the numbers minus the ones that aren't in cycles?

Comment: Revoked my answer since it was too simplistic for what you need to do. There's no easy way to do this. You're going to have to analyze each one.

Comment: @ Justin Buchanan. I would like all the loops from the given numbers, in this case [[28, 36], [69, 17, 43]]. The answer by malbarbo looks perfect for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a interesting [non trivial](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0204007) task. Anyway, the pythonic way of doing it is to use a library. This is a solution using [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/)

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.cycles import simple_cycles
g = nx.DiGraph()    
g.add_edges_from([(28, 36), (17, 43), (36, 28), (43, 69), (69, 17), (8, 94)])
print list(simple_cycles(g))
```

Output

```
[[28, 36], [69, 17, 43]]
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen. It allows for multiple loops, same-valued tuples, nested loops, things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not so pythonic but shouldn't be such a headache:
1. Organize data in a dictionary (or list of tuples...)
2. Until dictionary empty:
2.1 Get one pair of key, value  - first pair
2.2 Start a follow for this pair: Until reaching first pair again, or reaching a value that has no key - dead-end (like 8 in your example)
2.2.1 Save current pair to a buffer
2.2.2 Move to next pair - which its key is the current's value
2.3 After follow ends, check why
2.3.1 If reached first pair, save the buffer to the list of cycles
2.3.2 If reached a dead-end do nothing
2.4 Anyway, delete all buffer content from dictionary
3 Finished!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that tries to deal with multi-way paths.

```
#!python3
import collections
import io

Test_data = """
28 36
17 43
36 28
43 69
69 17
8 94
36 17
43 28
"""

# Read in data

with io.StringIO(Test_data.strip()) as f:
    pairs = [tuple(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in f if line.strip()]

# Temporary structures for cleanup

keys = set([p[0] for p in pairs])
values = set([p[1] for p in pairs])

# Clean up data

mapping = collections.defaultdict(list)

for k,v in pairs:
    if k in values and v in keys:
        mapping[k].append(v)

# Find cycles

cycles = set()

def find_cycle(cycle):
    target = cycle[0]

    for v in mapping[cycle[-1]]:
        if v == target:
            cycles.add(tuple(sorted(cycle)))
            continue

        if v in seen:
            continue
        else:
            seen.add(v)
            find_cycle(cycle+[v])

# Search for cycles starting at each possible point (might find shorter cycle)

for k in mapping.keys():
    seen = set()
    find_cycle([k])

print(cycles)
```